# from _ to _ years old

Tags: prepositions

- She works with children from 5 to 10 years old.
- She works with children from 5 to 10 years.

1. Which one is correct?

Some natives said that they'd say "She works with children aged 5 to 10".

Do you agree? Is this how most people speak?

2. What about those 2 sentences? Are they wrong at all?

Some natives said:
The use of **from**, rather than **of**, implies working with them for 5 years, i.e. **throughout that age range**.

Is that true? I should use "OF" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

1: *She works with children from 5 to 10 years old* is best. You only really see *5 to 10 years*, without *old*, on the boxes of toys and games, or on clothes (as the other respondent mentioned---although you can see we slightly disagree on whether the *old* is more natural).

*She works with children aged 5 to 10* is fine, maybe even better. The truth is that there are various ways to say this naturally. Other possibilities:

- She works with children between 5 and 10 [years old]
- She works with children between the ages of 5 and 10

2: The basic answer is no, you don't **need** to use *of*. Other answers may wish to go into more detail. I can see how your natives might have thought that the *from* variant implies a 'throughout' reading, but this is a) wrong and b) too literal an understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In English, we usually do say that someone's age is "[x] *years old*". If you were stating your, or someone else's age you should definitely include the word "old" as it wouldn't be correct without.

However, in the context of your example - where you are stating an **age range** rather than an age, it is perfectly normal to omit the word "old" and say "*from [x]-[y] years*". For example, the labels on children's clothes often state "1-2 years", "2-3 years" etc in place of size.

So, in the case of your example, you could say either and it would be understood.

With a range of ages, you would have to use "from" [x] - [y]. Only when speaking about a single could you use "of", for example, "I work with children of 5".

Comment: Thank you a lot!